# Mirror a GitHub repository using the source-repositories API directly

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-source-repositories

The cloud console provides an interface for mirroring a repository from GitHub.

When you use this feature it creates a [mirrorConfig](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos#MirrorConfig) on the repository which can be read from the API. The API itself however does not seem to provide a way to write to this config.

Example when trying to make a repository with a mirrorConfig

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "repo.mirror_config",
            "description": "mirror_config is a read-only field and must not be set"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
        "requestId": "*****"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to programmatically create mirrored source repositories in Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest) API does provide a [Method: projects.repos.create](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos/create), but no method to mirror from GitHub. 
Rather use Cloud Console GUI to set up mirroring: [Mirror a GitHub repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository#mirror_a_github_repository).
If this is a feature request, you should open it in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Is the answer :(

Source: George's comment above (Google Cloud Platform Support team)